# Calling a javascript function in html page embedded in an object tag

Tags: javascript, html, object-tag

I have a page which contains another page embedded inside an object tag.
Now I want to call a javascript function from the "parent"-page. To be specific: The parent page wants to call a function, which resides inside the embedded code.
Former I used iframes but they caused some nasty bugs with Firefox, so I don't want to use them anymore.

Edit:
So, my question is: what would be the best way to achieve this, when using an object tag?

Here's some example to illustrate what I want to do:

I have a HTML page "parent.html" inside this page there is some Javascript inside a  tag. This parent.html also has an  tag and the src of this tag is another HTML page, let's call it child.html. The child.html page has something like:

Here's some pseudo code:

in Child.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="child.js"></script>
```

in Child.js:

```
function getSomething(){
    return something;
}
```

in Parent.html:

```
<object id="childObject" data="child.html" width="850" height="510">
</object>

<script>
    // Here I want to access the function from the child.js
    // I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:
    var something = document.getElementById('childObject').contentDocument.getSomething();
</script>
```

Now:
In the Javascript inside the parent.html I need to call a function from the child.js.
How can I achieve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have a question to ask or a problem to show us? As is, this is more of an update on your status.

Comment: sorry it is not question

Comment: Provide some code to illustrate your problem; besides, even better if you can post what you have done so far in achieving what you expect to have as the solution.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was too tired yesterday to realize I forgot to write down the question after briefly explaining the problem :) I hope you can understand, what I want to do and what my question is.

Answer (score 1):

Using `contentWindow` instead of `contentDocument` works for me:

```
<object id="childObject" data="child.html" width="850" height="510">
</object>

<script>
    var something = document.getElementById('childObject').contentWindow.getSomething();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try This

```
<object id="childObject" data="child.html" width="850" height="510">
```

```
<script>
var something = document.getElementById("childObject").parentElement.getSomething();
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't work and I think it's not really what I want to do, because my js calling the .getSomething() is loaded in the parent.html, but thanks for your response :)